# How can encode json url hindi text into normal hindi text?

Tags: android, json

```
{"page":[
       {"pageid":"11099",
        "title":"Hindi Sms",
        "type":"0",
        "desc":"\u0936\u093e\u092f\u0930\u0940 \u090f\u0938\u090f\u092e\u090f\u0938:$@|11156|@$:4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon
       }  
     ]
 }
```

I am developing one hindi sms collection app in that app, i have get that sms  from server to my app through url, so if I open that url webbrowser it returns response same as the above.

- How can convert that text as hindi sms programtically in android ?
- Does anyone have any experience of this problem? Does anyone have any tips and advice as to how can Debugging what's really going on here is outside my area of expertise.

please help out from this problem.

Comment: hi, did u got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Following line of code is what you will need. First parse the JSON and get the HINDI string and pass it to the method below and it should be in readable format.

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode(String)
```

Comment: page.setDesc(c.getString(TextUtils.htmlEncode(TAG_DESC)));  am implement ur code but still same problem?

Answer (score 0):

First parse the JSONResponse...And get Into one String like

```
String jsStr = jsonObj.getString("ypour parameter Name");



TextUtils.htmlEncode(jsStr);
YourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(jsStr));
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the response you have is in `json` format so you would need to parse it via native **android json library** and nothing else.

To convert the given format to a particular language look what webservice has been provided to you as there must be some or if not you may look into google translator services for conversion.

**Looking at your response I feel there are some client provided api's via web services.**

**---- Edit 1----**

The data is getting displayed as is because you are displaying `html` as normal `Sting text`.

Using , after parsing json and getting value of **desc object**.

```
   Html.fromhtml("\u0936\u093e\u092f\u0930\u0940 \u090f\u0938...");
```

will do the trick.

**---- Edit 2----**

```
page.setDesc(c.getString(TAG_DESC));
```

> Look you get the desc object from json in the above line and set it to
>   your object.

**You have to use my code where you get this object to display text in TextView object.**

**i.e. this way,**

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(page.getDesc()));
```

or

```
yourTextView.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode(page.getDesc());
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion but thing is i use same url in iphoen app it's working fine but in android what data it display in webbrower that data only it display in app also  ..not exact hindi text?

Comment: page.setDesc(c.getString(TAG_DESC)); this way am get from json desc then how can add ur code to that line?

Comment: sorry .right now also i geting same data with encode not normal hindisms

Comment: Hope this time it works , look at the edit. are you using this with textview?

Comment: TextView Adapt_text = (TextView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.adapter_text);
//  Adapt_text.setText(entry.getAdpt_text()); my code which i write?

Comment: right now i change that code as  Adapt_text.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode(entry.getAdpt_text()));  but it also not work...first after parse url i need chage that encode text into normal text?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25652/discussion-between-areddy-and-pks)

Comment: "yourTextView.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode(page.getDesc());" - Not working !